# Renaming namespace in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Is it possible to rename namespace that is already loaded?

In my case I have Clojure script with namespace, let's say `main-xxx`, and lots of other scripts, which use `main` namespace (modifying them is not possible, `main` and `main-xxx` namespaces have same functions, but with different implementations).

What I would like to do is to make something like `(alias 'main 'main-xxx)` - but in order it to work I would have to call `alias` in each script (which cannot be done).

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know if a namespace can be renamed, and if it could, I think it would be a bad idea anyway. You can use `in-ns`, `unalias`, and `alias` to change the namespace mappings in an ns you cannot edit, but this is still an inferior solution to simply making a new version of the namespace (even if you cannot edit it, you can manually make a modified version that can be edited).

Comment: Yea, something I would need is 'global' or 'inherited' alias. But, if I understand correctly, there are no such things in Clojure.

Comment: Pragmatically, I think you could use protocols to get what you want - if the code is written in terms of the functions of some protocol, then the client can swap out implementations of that protocol as they please.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work the way you want. You *can* call alias in each namespace (you just in-ns each namespace and call it), but aliasing doesn't affect functions defined before the alias — their bindings already refer to the original namespace's vars. You'd need to actually redefine the namespace's vars in order to change what functions are called through them.